# JSON object format/merge

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these two variables below:

```js
var parent: [{
  "SNO": "869",
  "Name": "ABC"
}, {
  "SNO": "800",
  "Name": "CCC"
}]
var Cost = [{
  "NO": "869",
  "Amnt": 100
}, {
  "NO": "800",
  "Amnt": 200
}, {
  "NO": "800",
  "Amnt": 560
}]

and the end updated result I want something like.
{
  "parent": [{
      "SNO": "869",
      "Name": "ABC",
      "Cost": [{
          "NO": "869",
          "Amnt": 100
        },
        {
          "NO": "869",
          "Amnt": 200
        },
        {
          "NO": "869",
          "Amnt": 560
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "SNO": "800",
      "Name": "XYZ",
      "Cost": [{
          "NO": "800",
          "Amnt": 100
        },
        {
          "NO": "800",
          "Amnt": 200
        },
        {
          "NO": "800",
          "Amnt": 560
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone suggest me how to make it possible.

Comment: *Can someone suggest me*? Sure. Loop over `parent` and  create a temp object. Set `temp.something = parent.something`. Then inside that loop, loop over `cost` and get matching objects. Now set this list to `temp.cost` and TA-DA!!!

Comment: It's two arrays containing objects. First you want to create a hashmap from the Parent array with the SNO number as the key and a new object with the keys SNO (null),Name (null) and Cost(empty array). Then you reduce the Cost array into that hashmap. Inside the reduce, select the correct parent by using the SNO numbers, then push the Cost object into the SNO array field inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the reference to the same parents.

```js
var parent = [{ SNO: "869", Name: "ABC" }, { SNO: "800", Name: "CCC" }],
    cost = [{ NO: "869", Amnt: 100 }, { NO: "800", Amnt: 200 }, { NO: "800", Amnt: 560 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = { Parent: parent.map(function (a) { return hash[a.SNO] = a; }) };

cost.forEach(function (a) {
    (hash[a.NO].Cost = hash[a.NO].Cost || []).push(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.parent = [{
    "SNO": "869",
    "Name": "ABC"
  }, {
    "SNO": "800",
    "Name": "CCC"
  }];

  $scope.Cost = [{
    "NO": "869",
    "Amnt": 100
  }, {
    "NO": "800",
    "Amnt": 200
  }, {
    "NO": "800",
    "Amnt": 560
  }];

  $scope.mergeArr = function(arr1, arr2) {
    var arrTmp = [];
    if (Array.isArray(arr1)) {
      arrTmp.push(...arr1);
    } else {
      arrTmp.push(arr1);
    }

    arrTmp.forEach(function(item) {
      var costArr = arr2.filter(function(item2) {
        return item2.NO === item.SNO;
      });

      if (costArr.length > 0) {
        if (!item.COST) {
          item["COST"] = [];
        }

        costArr.forEach(function(cost) {
          item.COST.push(cost);
        })
      }
    });
    console.log(arrTmp);
    return {
      "Parent": arrTmp
    };
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <ui>
      <li ng-repeat="project in mergeArr(parent, Cost).Parent">
        {{project.SNO}} - {{project.Name}}
      </li>
    </ui>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Pengyy**, it says:  arr1.forEach is not a function

Comment: @Saleem can confirm that the `parent` is type of `array`?

Comment: at a time its storing one value dynamically. var Parent= $scope.beta[i];

Comment: @Saleem ok, for this situation, you have to define an array and push the one value to the array, then use the function i have made.

Comment: can you post what's in $scope.beta[i]?

Comment: {
  "SNO": "869",
  "Name": "ABC"
}

Comment: The above is the object I am taking in Parent one by one.

Comment: @Saleem check for the answer again, i have made some change for your situation.

Comment: **Pengyy**, your above code is working quite fine, but one more thing I need in that is I want to use ng-repeat and display that in table by grouping by parent object.

Comment: **Pengyy**, I just updated my question code to look like just I wanted to, can you change your solution accordingly.

Comment: @Saleem I have update the answer which adjust to ng-repeate of angularjs. hope it helps.

Comment: @Saleem hi, if this answer helped, please mark as an answer as a reward to those like me who answer questions on SO.